# SQL join causes SUM to multiply

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns expected results grouped by week:

```
SELECT Week(display.date) AS date_granularity,
                `display`.`site`,
                `display`.`ad_unit`,
                Sum(`display`.`revenue`)
FROM   `display`
WHERE `display`.`date` BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-15'
       AND ( `display`.`ad_unit` = 'IC1' )
GROUP  BY `date_granularity`,
          `display`.`site`,
          `display`.`ad_unit`
```

Results:
[results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOQth.png)
(Sorry, it wouldn't let me insert the image inline. Blacked out the names of our clients for privacy)

But when I add a join:

```
SELECT Week(display.date) AS date_granularity,
                `display`.`site`,
                `display`.`ad_unit`,
                Sum(`display`.`revenue`)
FROM   `display`
JOIN `traffic`
               ON Week(`traffic`.`date`) = Week(`display`.`date`)
WHERE `display`.`date` BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-15'
       AND ( `display`.`ad_unit` = 'IC1' )
GROUP  BY `date_granularity`,
          `display`.`site`,
          `display`.`ad_unit`
```

The results are heavily multiplied: [results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eidSj.png)

I'm pulling my hair out here. I've read similar questions where they were advised to use a subquery, but I don't know how to do that. Any advice?

(If some of my syntax looks weird, it's because this query was generated by Laravel)

Comment: Why are you joining with `traffic`, you don't use anything from that table?

Comment: `JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT WEEK(date) AS week FROM traffic) AS t ON t.week = WEEK(display.date)`

Comment: @Barmar's response worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN actually multiplies the records. If you have 5 rows in `display` and 7 rows in `traffic` for a given week, you'll get 5 * 7 = 35 rows. Those are then grouped and summed.

Guessing what you might be up to, one of the following approaches might work:

1. Either tighten the filter condition so there is only one row in `traffic` per week
2. or join after the aggregation, that is with a subquery:

   ```sql
   SELECT ...
   FROM (SELECT ... FROM display ... GROUP BY ... /* your current query */)
       AS grouped
   JOIN traffic ON Week(traffic.date) = Week(grouped.date)
   ```